# Fun with Flags part 11: flexable flags

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cipher, flags

The answer to this puzzle consists of two 8-letter words which should explain what is going on with the title of this puzzle.

[image: fwf11]

---

<sub>More [fun with flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A60396+%22fun+with+flags%22)</sub>

Comment: I THOUGHT this was gonna be fine... until I saw Imperator Julius V went to Brazil. #empireofbrazil #huehuehuehue

Comment: Rot13(Gur bssvpvny Oenmvyvna synt unf 27 fgnef bs 5 qvssrerag fvmrf. Lbhe synt unf 18 fgnef bs 3 qvssrerag fvmrf, naq gurve cbfvgvbaf qrivngrf fvtavsvpnagyl sebz gur bssvpvny bar. V thrff gung guvf vf bar bs gur znal fhogyr sbezf gung lbh hfrq gb uvqr fbzr vasbezngvba ba gurz.)

Comment: @VictorStafusa You are correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two eight-letters words are:

> **MISSPELL FLEXIBLE**, which the title does.

The obvious:

> The eight national flags here have been subtly modified to encode something. Some encodings are more obvious than others. Let's start with:

The Seychelles

> The top left flag is the actual flag of the Seychelles. The other flags are permutations of the five colours. If we take the nth permutation in "lexicographic order" as the nth letter of the alphabet, we get **ASCII Z**.
>
>  (Lexico-what? Okay, assign a number to each colour, so that the original blue, yellow, red, white and green corresponds to 12345. Now you can produce all 5! = 120 permutations in order, so that the mth pemutation is larger than the nth if m is larger than n. The original flag is A. To get B, swap white and green to get 12354. The 2345 can be permuted in 4! = 24 different ways, which goes up to X. For Y and Z, the blue part must be swapped, too. The Z in the answer is 21354.)

United States

> These stars sure look strange. The six rows of seven stars each are binary numbers, where outlined stars are 0, filled stars are 1. The resulting numbers are ASCII codes of **Yin Yang Alphalines a**. (Spaces added for your reading convenience.)
>
>  That clearly means that we're headed to ...

South Korea

> I didn't know what to do here for quite some time until I found out that [Yin Yang Alphalines](https://omniglot.com/conscripts/yyal.htm) is the name of a font that tries to emulate the trigraphs in the Korean flag.
>
>  Decoding the flags, I get **Antiker Code G**. That sounds like another fancy font. And we see a pattern emerging: Each hint has an extra letter. We have eight different flags and we are looking for two eight-letter words ...

Iran

> The repeated writings of *Allahu Akbar* between the stripes of the flag are interrupted by writing in [Antiker Code](https://geocachen.be/geocaching/geocache-puzzels-oplossen/antiker-code/), an alphabet apparently popular with geocachers. The writing reads: **Slash and Pipe Code W**.

Eswatini

> The bar motif in the shield has been changed to a [slash-and-pipe code](https://www.cachesleuth.com/slashandpipe.html), which reads **Futurama Alienese Z**. On to ...

Mongolia

> The golden symbols between the bars are symbols of the [Futurama Alien alphabet](https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/futurama.htm). They spell **Braille D**.

Brazil:

> Stars of equal size can be grouped to form [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille) patterns, which read **Morse S** – the gestalt principles of similarity and of proximity at work, I guess. We're getting close, on to ...

Belize

> The leaves of the somewhat naked wreath have two sizes, which can be interpreted as the dots and dashes of [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse), which gives us **Reorder G**.

The final answer:

> The extra letters of all countries spell **ZAGWZDSG**. There are two pieces of information we haven't used: The "Imperator Iulius V" and "XII" on the flags of Brazil and Belize and the instruction to "reorder".
>
>  "Imperator Iulius" refers to [Caesar code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), of course. Applying a Caesar shift of 12 yields **LMSILPES**, which can be reordered to **MISSPELL**. A Caesar shift of 5 yields **EFLBEIXL**, an anagram of **FLEXIBLE**.
>
>  Whew!

Credit where it's due:

> Stiv found what to do in Brazil and Belize and the first word; Braegh found the second word and the connection to the title.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck right now and also exhausted from my vexillological exploits and need to go to bed. Perhaps more tomorrow. If someone else wants to wrap this up: Go ahead, don't be shy.

Comment: More progress for you - rot13(Vg'f Oenmvy lbh jnag sbe Oenvyyr - tebhc ol fgne fvmr, yrsg gb evtug fcryyf ZBEFR F. Gura Oryvmr hfrf Zbefr pbqr jvgu gur gjb fvmrf bs yrns orvat qbgf naq qnfurf; ernqvat pybpxjvfr ernqf ERBEQRE T. Vs lbh nccyl gur Pnrfne-12 fuvsg gb nyy yrggref, gur yrggref pna or nantenzzrq gb ZVFFCRYY. Guvf znl or pbvapvqrapr, nf gurer'f nyfb n Pnrfne 5 vaqvpngrq va Oenmvy.)

Comment: rot13(ymj xfrj qjyyjwx WTY5 yt fs fsflwfr tk "kqjcngqj" ytt, fsi ns ymj ynyqj, "kqjcfgqj" nx f rnxxujqqnsl tk ny.)

Comment: Ah, thanks, @Stiv. I didn't see that. I also thought that I tried what you proposed on Belize (in anearly stage, when I was still just guessing), but I must have misdecoded, because  it was a dead end for me.

Comment: And thanks to you, too, @Braegh. Your comment is a bit self-describing in that it doesn't use rot13 as advertised ... `:)`

Comment: Oops. Can fix. Might be more appropriate like this.

Comment: @Braegh: No sweat, it's all good. Thanks again. (I often rot13 spoilers and then copy the wrong text for what effectively is a very non-spoilery rot26. Your comment is consistent at least.)

Comment: @MOehm Nice solve :) rot12(Hvs wbhsbrsr igs tcf 'fscfrsf' kog owasr oh hvs Gsmqvszzsg tzou, gc hvoh hvs swuvh qcibhfm tzoug dcwbh hc soqv chvsf'g sbqcrwbu ashvcrg wb o qwfqizof kom. Pih ct qcifgs wh qob ps igsr hc ush hc hvs twboz hkc kcfrg, zwys mci rwr (W rwrb'h fsozwns hvwg ibhwz W gok mcif obgksf).)

Comment: Thanks. Nice visual puzzle with a cool mechanic. rot13(Nun, qvqa'g frr gung. V gubhtug V zvffrq n uvag nobhg gur ragel cbvag, ohg gur pbqrf ner n evat jurer lbh unir gb thrff bar gb trg n sbbg va gur qbbe. Naq V qvq gung: V fnj HFN vzzrqvngryl, ohg pbhyqa'g haqrefgnaq vg. V nyfb sbhaq gur Shghenzn guvat jvgu na vzntr frnepu naq thrffrq gur Zbefr pbqr, ohg nccneragyl ohatyrq vg.)